# What is the most efficient way to parse json in jquery?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I am using json data and iterating it through jquery and displaying my results...

Using `var jsonObj = JSON.parse(HfJsonValue);` works in `firefox` but not in `IE6`....

`HfjsonValue` is a json string which is returned from my `aspx code behind page`... SO i dont use ajax... Any suggestion to get my json parsed better and cross browser one...

Comment: JSON is JavaScript Object Notation, it doesn't need parsing in JS. You can just start using it as a regular object.

Comment: @RaYell i ve tried it... But that didn't work

Comment: You might have to `eval()` the JSON first.

Comment: If he has JSON in a string, he has to call eval() on it in order to turn it into a object. JSON.parse is a "safe" (meaning that it won't execute harmful code) way to parse a string containing JSON.

Comment: @Greg K - using `eval` is never a good way. It probably creates more problems then it solves.

Comment: I appreciate it's frowned upon and not very safe. I should have included what Nick said but was lazy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably this: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

...uh of course, that's only if you want to use jQuery 1.4. :) I think that the JSON built-in functionality is a fairly new addition to the browsers that actually try to implement standards.

**Edit**

Just as a follow up, you can turn a JSON string into a JavaScript object by calling the "eval" function on it:

```
var obj = eval('({"name":"John"})');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

That should give the same result as the jQuery parseJSON above. The difference is that the JavaScript "eval" function will run whatever code is inside, so if the source of your JSON is an external site or another untrusted source, that source could inject malicious code into the string you are expecting to only contain JSON.

I believe that there is a new recommendation that browsers implement built-in JSON parsing, which would enforce the JavaScript object literal format on the string, which would provide a safe alternative to "eval".

**Edit 2**

Having never actually used `eval` to process JSON, I incorrectly assumed my example would work. It's fixed now with the addition of the surrounding braces.

Comment: You should include brackets inside the eval parentheses: `eval('({"name":"John"})');` If you want raw speed, `var obj = new Function('return {"name":"John"}')` will be quickest. Be aware however, that jQuery.parseJSON checks the JSON to ensure it is valid JSON; and not malicious code. Both the `new Function` and the `eval` methods do not. I would recommend jQuery.parseJSON.

Comment: Are you expecting a really big string of JSON? If speed really is a concern (ie. you are expecting a large JSON string and need to perform well on really slow machines, or something similar) and you are the one controlling the JSON string, there's no reason to be afraid of using eval or the Function syntax Matt mentioned (if you are 100% sure that the JSON string will always be valid JSON and nothing malicious). However, it might (maybe) be harder to find syntax errors in the JSON using those methods.

Comment: You should note that the jquery parse operates on strings while eval operates on objects. `eval({"I'm":"broken"})` will work, `jQuery.parseJSON('{"I'm":"broken"}')` will fail but `jQuery.parseJSON('{"I\'m":"broken"}')` works.  The eval example above will return a syntax error.

Comment: You're right @Error454, I've corrected my example. You must put braces around the JSON string when using it with `eval`. Just to clarify though, `eval` is indeed meant to be used with strings, not objects.